# From acceleration spectrum to velocity

Tags: fourier-analysis, fast-fourier-transform

Searching a totally irrelevant matter, i came across the following patent:

https://www.google.com/patents/US5744723

, which proposes a framework to calculate velocity from machine vibration data.

So i was wondering, is there an *analytic* way to get from acceleration spectrum ( trivial fft analysis ) to velocity estimate?

Has anybody come across a study that deals with this topic?